# Best way to display a list of links to articles?

Tags: lists, hyperlinks

I have a page that links to other pages on my Wordpress website. At the moment, I am displaying them in an unordered list. However, in my opinion, it looks a bit cluttered. Plus, I'm afraid that the links are a little too close to one another. Example:

[image]

Is there a better more user-friendly way to do this?

Comment: Is this a list of importance to you? Like for instance, is the first link #1 on your list of "how much I like this?" Or is it just a unordered list?

Comment: @Majo0od Completely un-ordered. A glorified menu of sorts!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Use each link as an item separator

Separate the links from the descriptions and place them in a vertical list.  With proper spacing it should be clear where each item begins and ends without the need for bullet point dots.

[image: links]

Answer (score 2):

I like DaveAlger's suggestion.

Here are two other layout options that might work for you. I think it depends on what kind of content you have.

[image: Representative icons above each link, then the link title and description. These would just stack vertically for as many links as you have.]

[image: left-column hyperlink title with a description on the right. These would stack vertically one by one for as many links as you have.]

Answer (score 1):

The most user friendly list at the bottom of a blog post, at least for me, is to have no list at all, but a single link titled 'Read this next'. This might need human curation rather than just tag matching, but it means a lot to me. I can only click one article's title at a time, and someone has already done the hard work and chosen that for me? I am sold.